# Pandas.DataFrame.read_sql to read as float32 instead of float64

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm using `pd.DataFrame.read_sql` to retrieve a large number of records from a SQL database causing a huge amount of memory to be used.

I noticed that the `dtype` of the numerical values are `float64`, but I only require `float32` dtypes on most of the numerical values.

Is it possible to retrieve values via `read_sql` as `float32`?

Comment: No http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html ... :/

Comment: You could convert it once read using `.astype('int32')`